# The file 'src' is not a valid here because it doesn't expose a type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver

This is a very strange error. The website will work for some time and suddenly stop and display this error message: [image: Error]

And when this error raise all what I need is to rename the web-application .dll file to something else and return it to the original name!

Are there any suggestions please.

Comment: is this a "web site" project, or a "web application" project? it *sounds* like the first: any chance of migrating to the second? (it tends to work better, in my experience)

Comment: Do you use the folder App_Code? That code is dynamically compiled runtime.

Comment: this a web-application not website 

and it's in c#.

@Luuk No App_Code folder in my web-application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I could not solve this one , but when I republished the web-application the problem solved.

It might be because some Dll files was corrupted .

Answer (score 7):

You can also get this error if your page's @Register tag for the ASCX control sets Src to the .ascx.cs file instead of the .ascx file.

That is, if you have this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myLib" TagName="myControl" Src="~/Controls/myControl.ascx.cs" %>
```

... instead of this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myLib" TagName="myControl" Src="~/Controls/myControl.ascx" %>
```

When I encountered this error, I just removed the ".cs" from the @Register tag and rebuilt. Problem solved.